# Employee Classes - Python

Tags: python, class

Write a class named Employee that holds the following data about an employee in attributes: name, ID number, department, and job title.

Once you have written the class, write a program that creates three Employee objects to hold the following data:

Susan Meyers - 47899 - Accounting - Vice President
Mark Jones - 39119 - IT - Programmer
Joy Rogers - 81774 - Manufacturing - Engineer

^ This is the problem I'm stuck on. I believe I have the first part of the code correct, but I don't understand what to do for the second part of the program to create Employee objects.

Here is my code so far...

emp.py file

```
#create a class named Employee
class Employee:

    #initialize the attributes
    def __init__(self, name, id, department, title):
        self.__name = name
        self.__id = id
        self.__department = department
        self.__title = title

    #set the attributes
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_id(self, id):
        self.__id = id

    def set_department(self, department):
        self.__department = department

    def set_title(self, title):
        self.__title = title

    #return the attributes
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_id(self):
        return self.__id

    def get_department(self):
        return self.__department

    def get_title(self):
        return self.__title

    #return the objects state as a string

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Name: ' + self.__name + \
               '\nID number: ' + self.__id + \
               '\nDepartment: ' + self.__department + \
               '\nTitle: ' + self.__title
```

and here is my main function where the second part is going to go...

```
 import emp


def main():
    #Create three employee objects
    emp1 = emp.Employee('name', 'id', 'department', 'title')
    emp2 = emp.Employee('name', 'id', 'department', 'title')
    emp3 = emp.Employee('name', 'id', 'department', 'title')

    #create three Employee objects for each attribute
    emp1.set_name('Susan Meyers')
    emp1.set_id('47899')
    emp1.set_department('Accounting')
    emp1.set_title('Vice President')

    emp2.set_name('Mark Jones')
    emp2.set_id('39119')
    emp2.set_department('IT')
    emp2.set_title('Programmer')

    emp3.set_name('Joy Rogersr')
    emp3.set_id('81774')
    emp3.set_department('Manufacturing')
    emp3.set_title('Engineer')

    print()
    print(emp1)
    print()
    print(emp2)
    print()
    print(emp3)


main()
```

So with this code, I am now getting the correct answer of this:

```
Employee 1:
Name: Susan Meyers
ID number: 47899
Department: Accounting
Title: Vice President

Employee 2:
Name: Mark Jones
ID number: 39119
Department: IT
Title: Programmer

Employee 3:
Name: Joy Rogers
ID number: 81774
Title: Programmer

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `susan =  emp.Employee('Susan Meyers',  47899 , 'Accounting' , 'Vice President')`

Comment: I know there is no code in the second part. That is because I wasn't sure how to continue. Wright, is that creating an object for the class?

Comment: Google is your friend. type something like "create new instance of a class in python"... you'll see dozens of tutorials. For example [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/class-python)

Comment: Okay, cool. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is, it's creating a new object instance of the class meaning each of the objects will have the methods of the class, for example, you'll be able to do susan.set_name('Something') which would change the name attribute for susan to 'Something'. @Classicalclown

Comment: Oh, I think that comment really helps. Let me work with that. Thanks! @Wright

Comment: As explained in the first comment from @Wright, you don't need to call the setters - the properties are already set via the constructor.  Also, not that you need them here, but your getters/setters are not idiomatic Python.  There are multiple ways to support properties in Python classes.  The simplest is to not obscure them with `__` and just make them directly visible.  Next up is the property decorator syntax, [described here](http://stackabuse.com/python-properties/).  I usually avoid the even more complicated ways (`getattr()` and friends) but I mention them here for completeness.

Comment: Another person learning Python from someone teaching Java.

Comment: Agreed - I had 16 years of Java under my belt when I first started learning Python, and there was so much I had to UN-learn.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

You have inpored you python file emp.py that has the class 'Employee' with `import emp` statement.
Now ,

```
emp1=emp.Employee('kee',1,'CSE','SE')
print emp1
```

Will create the object and stores its pointer to emp1.

Comment: Hmm, so I would do this for each employee and emp.Employee is using the imported file and class correct? So is that creating an Employee object to hold data?

Comment: Yea.i get it. Take a look at the python documentation link I've shared. That will have more detailed explanation. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you! Will do

Answer (score 0):

Import emp.py

```
    from emp import Employee
```

Go ahead and create 3 Employee objects:

```
    def main():
        emp1 = Employee("name", id, department, title)
        emp2 = Employee("name", id, department, title)
        emp3 = Employee("name", id, department, title)
```

Answer (score 0):

The emp.py file could be:

```
    class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name, employee_id, department, title):
        self.name = name
        self.employee_id = employee_id
        self.department = department
        self.title = title

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} , id={}, is in {} and is a {}.'.format(self.name, self.employee_id, self.department, self.title)
```

A couple of notes:

- [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) is a built-in function that returns the “identity” of an object.  It is best not use that as an attribute, it might confuse other programmers.
- The attributes should not have double underscores, aka dunders.
- In Python, there is no need for setters and getters.
- Add a **str** method for well-formatted printing

Then the second would be:

```
from emp import Employee

def main():

    # Create three employee objects
    emp1 = Employee(name='Susan Meyers', employee_id='47899', department='Accounting', title='Vice President')
    emp2 = Employee(name='Mark Jones', employee_id='39119', department='IT', title='Programmer')
    emp3 = Employee(name='Joy Rogersr', employee_id='81774', department='Manufacturing', title='Engineer')

    print(emp1, sep='/n/n')
    print(emp2, sep='/n/n')
    print(emp3, sep='/n/n')
```

Instance attributes can be set when constructing. This saves many lines of code.